# Page not found (404) at /remove/, Hy i am a beginner and i want to delete data then i get this error ,please help me to solve this problem

Tags: django, django-templates

```
 urls.py
```

'''

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index' ),
    path('form', views.form, name='form' ),
    path('about', views.about, name='about' ),
    path('add_data', views.add_data, name='add_data' ),
    path('remove', views.remove, name='remove' ),
    path('remove/<int:emp_id>', views.remove, name='remove' ),
]
```

'''

```
 views.py
```

'''

```
def remove(request,emp_id = 0):
    if emp_id:
        try:
            emp_removed=Members.objects.get(id=emp_id)
            emp_removed.delete()
            return HttpResponse('remover data successfully..')
        except:
            pass
    emps=Members.objects.all()
    context={
        'emp':emps
    }
    return render(request,'remove.html', context)
```

'''

```
 remove.html
```

'''

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
       {% for i in emp %}
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/remove/{{emp.id}}">{{i.firstname}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul><ul class="dropdown-menu">
       {% for i in emp %}
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/remove/{{emp.id}}">{{i.firstname}}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

i want to delete some item from my template and i am getting the above mentioned error, if anyone know the answer please tell me ...
[This page shows when i run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKyQE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add forward slash `/` at the end of all the routes so:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index' ),
    path('form/', views.form, name='form' ),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about' ),
    path('add_data/', views.add_data, name='add_data' ),
    path('remove/', views.remove, name='remove' ),
    path('remove/<int:emp_id>/', views.remove, name='remove' ),
]
```

Then enter requested url as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/remove/`.

Answer (score 0):

That problem is probably related to the directory your template is in.
Verify the `TEMPLATES DIRS` in `settings.py` file and verify if the template you have (.html file) is in the same directory.
Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/templates/#configuration) for more information about the topic.

Comment: 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,'templates'], i already did this still i'm getting this error

Comment: Can you show your django project directory root organization and files?

Comment: Are your other views and templates working? If they are, that can mean a typo on the name of the file.